Seeking Cost-Effective Horizontal Scaling Solution for a Logging System on GCP
I'm facing a challenge with my current architecture on GCP and would appreciate any insights or advice you can provide.
Current Setup:
1.  API: Hosted in a container within Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).
2.  React UI: Served by a separate set of containers in GKE.
3.  OCR Job: This is a Kubernetes job within GKE, triggered by the API. The job executes custom OCR processes using a binary. It generates extensive logs, which are currently being streamed to Firestore. These logs are then displayed on the React frontend via the Firestore client. The job is managed and triggered through a queue system implemented in GKE.

Problem:
The OCR job binary streams logs for many hours, leading to substantial Firestore usage and associated costs due to the volume of data being written and stored.
Question:
We are looking for a way to horizontally scale this setup while minimizing costs, particularly those associated with Firestore. Is there a more cost-effective method or alternative for streaming and storing data in this scenario?
Any suggestions on architecture changes, services, or configuration adjustments that could help reduce costs without sacrificing performance would be greatly appreciated!


The binary in the Cloud Run job streams logs for many hours, significantly increasing our Firestore costs due to the volume of data being written and stored.

Have you tried to use the Realtime Database for your use case? If not, I recommend you try it because it has a totally different billing mechanism. The writes in the Realtime Database are free of charge.

Is there a more cost-effective method or alternative for streaming and storing data in this scenario?

I think that the Realtime Database is the solution in your case because it can help horizontally scale. Besides that, if you somehow reach a limitation you can then programmatically create as many Realtime Database new instances as you need.

Hey Dinesh. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
